# Android Custom Spinner Adapter issue

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

For my school project i am doing budget tracking app. I want to set categories to a spinner with custom layout.

This layout has ImageView and Text. I am storing data in sqlite. But i can not instantiate custom spinner adapter. On internet every sample uses activity but I'm using fragment. Thank you.

Here is the code

This is fragment

```
        public class TrnAddFragment extends Fragment {

        private Spinner categorySpn;
        private Spinner subCategorySpn;
        private Spinner sourceSpn;
        private EditText trnDate; //Add date picker spinner later
        private EditText trnAmount;
        private Switch debitOrCreditSwc;
        private TextView debitOrCreditStatus;
        private EditText trnDesc;
        private SpinnerAdapter adapter;



        public TrnAddFragment() {}


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View  view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trn_add, container, false);
            categorySpn = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.categorySpn);
            subCategorySpn =  (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.subCategorySpn);
            sourceSpn = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.sourceSpn);
            trnDate = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
            trnAmount = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.amountTxt);
            debitOrCreditSwc = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.debitOrCreditSwt);
            debitOrCreditStatus = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.debitOrCreditTxt);
            trnDesc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);


            //debit&credit switch listener
            debitOrCreditSwc.setChecked(true);
            debitOrCreditSwc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked){
                        debitOrCreditStatus.setText("Debit");
                    }else {
                        debitOrCreditStatus.setText("Credit");
                    }
                }
            });

            //debit&credit switch check&set before showing
            if (debitOrCreditSwc.isChecked()){
                debitOrCreditStatus.setText("Debit");
            }else {
                debitOrCreditStatus.setText("Credit");
            }


            //category spinner
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
            List<TrnCategory> categories = new ArrayList<>();
            categories = dbHelper.getAllCategory();

            // Resources passed to adapter to get image
            Resources resources = getResources();


//CODE LINE IS RED IN HERE
            adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_layout,categories,resources);
            categorySpn.setAdapter(adapter);



            //category spinner adapter 
            //ArrayAdapter<TrnCategory> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TrnCategory>(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.spn_category_txt,categories);
            //categorySpn.setAdapter(adapter);


            return view;
        }

    }
```

This is Custom Spinner Adapter

```
public class SpinnerAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<TrnCategory>{


    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<TrnCategory> data;
    public Resources resources;
    TrnCategory tempValues = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public SpinnerAdapter(TrnAddActivity activity, int resourceId, ArrayList data, Resources resources) {
        super(activity,resourceId,data);

        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.resources = resources;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout,parent,false);

        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (TrnCategory)data.get(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spn_txt);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.spn_img);


        if (position == 0){

            textView.setText("Please select");
        }else{

            image.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier("com.sabani.irfanyus.finalproject_1:mipmap/"
            + tempValues.getCategoryImageId(),null,null));

            textView.setText(tempValues.getCategoryName());
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

This is spinner layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spn_img"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spn_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Entity class

```
public class TrnCategory {

    private int id;
    private int categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryImageId;

    public TrnCategory() {
    }

    public TrnCategory(int categoryId, String categoryName, String categoryImageId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryImageId = categoryImageId;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryImageId() {
        return categoryImageId;
    }

    public void setCategoryImageId(String categoryImageId) {
        this.categoryImageId = categoryImageId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return categoryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your question is how to instanciate SpinnerAdapter from a Fragment subclass? Might Fragment.getActivity() help you?

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work out. Thanks by the way.  @C. L.

Comment: OK, so please specify what you mean by "i can not instantiate custom spinner adapter".

Comment: Sure. 
I changed like this and it says "Expression expected"  now. At the TrnAddActivity line.

adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(TrnAddActivity,R.layout.spinner_layout,categories,resources);
categorySpn.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: By the way sorry about my writing. This is the first time i am using here

Comment: try `adapter = new SpinnerAdapter((TrnAddActivity) this.getActivity(),R.layout.spinner_layout,catego‌​ries,resources);`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.
I have another problems but i will fix them.
Thanks @C. L.